# Selenium RC- How to capture dynamic text from an image and type the same in a text box next to it

Tags: selenium-rc

I am new to Selenium and have been trying to learn it using a registration web page. In the registration page, I have an image which has dynamic text which changes everytime a new registration is done. This text has to be captured and typed in as is inside a text box which is verified for completing registration. In Selenium RC, while inspecting element, the verifyv alue option is disabled.

When I use verifytext, the text is displayed but not value inside the image. Can someone suggest in RC, how I would capture the value inside the image without a Verifyvalue option as this is disabled.

Thanks
S

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about captcha, you can not automate captcha, as it is provided to avoid automation of functionality. 
To automate captcha you need human interaction. 
You can put break command or use input box, where you can type captcha value and then you can pass it to text box which is provided for captcha text. 
For sample script you can visit 
[HERE](http://radical-qa.blogspot.in/2012/03/selenium-ide-and-captcha.html)

Answer (score 0):

We write script but need to provide break point to insert CAPTCHA code manually. In this situation when script will be executed; every time CAPTCHA code must be entered manually. Use following script for that..

```
storeEval   |   prompt("Enter Captcha:")  | varName
type  |  id=recaptcha_response_field  |   ${varName}
```